# How do we set a password for the DigitalOcean Droplet created with Terraform

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I am given a task to create multiple servers on DigitalOcean. I noticed that there isn't an option to provide passwords during the server creation. I don't know if it sets the password randomly. Is there a way to output the set password after the Terraform applies? Or Should I give the password in a different way?

```
 resource "digitalocean_droplet" "user" {
  image  = "centos-7-x64"
  name   = "user"
  region = "blr1"
  size   = "s-1vcpu-2gb"
}
```

Ref. Link : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/droplet

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create users from TF. Instead you specify [ssh_keys](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/droplet#ssh_keys). Any user creation must be done outside of TF later on or using scripts in [user_data](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/droplet#user_data) script.